# Finding the leak from the Xcode 4 Profiler

Tags: xcode

My ipad app is receiving the Level 1 memory warning, so I ran the memory leak Profiler in Xcode 4. Sure enough, when I move one particular slider, it is causing a leak. Move it again, another leak and the leaked bytes escalate.

I am wondering if Xcode 4 provides an easy way to find out specifically which object is getting leaked. I have looked through the method from the slider movement; every time I use alloc/init, i then release it. It would be good know where Xcode is finding the leak since I cannot find it myself.

The Xcode 4 documentation references quite a number of tools. However I wonder if this documentation was not updated from Xcode 3 because those tools are not in the menus mentioned by the docs.

the slider action is:

```
-(IBAction) sensitivity:(UISlider *)slider{

self.grid.sensitivity=slider.value;
[self.grid setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

this by itself doesn't suggest a memory leak. However, the "setNeedsDisplay" method, which is quite a lengthy one, does not create a leak when it first runs, so why would it create a leak the second time it runs? All the inits/alloc in that code are released (there are only 3 objects created and released).

Comment: In this case, I'd say its fairly obvious its something in your slider or what your slider is controlling, if you link that code we could help with the specifics, as far as Instruments is concerned..see the other answers.

Comment: i added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it useful to run Build/Build and Analyze from the Menu. It doesn't catch everything and it flags a few false alarms, but it's a good (and easy) place to start for automated leak detection.

Comment: there is just a simple "Analyze" option under the Product menu in Xcode 4; is this the one you mean? When I run it, not much happens. It doesn't actually run my app on my device and no analytics appear anywhere within Xcode to suggest it found or analyzed anything.

Comment: @ansdrewjs: Not sure, I only have Xcode 3.2.5 on this machine. In my Menu it is under Build/ and the option is called "Build and Analyze" (shortcut shift-command-A). You must have a device attached to run it.

Comment: where do you see the results of the Analyze? I run what appears to be Analyze, and the program doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: A window pops up with the number of "results" indicated by a blue triangle. Screenshots at this link: http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/xcode.html